# Custom object 'game' doesn't have specified method

Tags: javascript, function, oop, methods

I'm trying to call a method `cardSelection()` from a `function game()` but instead I'm getting an error report which throws back to me the whole function with a "has no method cardSelection()" The idea is to access the method through the click of a button, which HTML tag is as follows:

```
<img id="PlayerCard0" class="card" src="images/Cards/Mario.png" alt="Mario" title="Mario" onclick="game.cardSelection('PlayerCard0')">
```

I'm not posting the whole Javascript as I believe this to be the case of a mere declaration error, anyhow, `game()` and `cardSelection()` were declared as follows:

```
function game()
{
...
this.cardSelection = function(card)
{
    var cardElem = document.getElementById(card);
    var id = cardElem.getAttribute("id");
    var call = document.getElementById("call");

    var select = function(card)
    {


        var found = 0;
        for (var card = 0, totalCards = 5; card < totalCards; card++)
        {
            if (document.getElementById("PlayerCard" + card + "selected"))
            {found++}
        }
        if (found == 0)
        {
            call.setAttribute("onclick", "changeHand()");
            call.childNodes[0].nodeValue = "Change";
        }
        if (found < 3)
        {
            id += "selected"
            setAttributes(cardElem,
            {
                "id" : id,
                "style": "position: relative; top: 1em;",
                "onclick" : "cardSelection('" + id + "')"
            });
        }
        else { return; }
    }
    var unselect = function (card)
    {
        cardElem.removeAttribute("style");
        id = id.replace("selected","");
        setAttributes(cardElem,
        {
            "id" : id,
            "onclick" : "cardSelection('" + id + "')"
        });
        var cardNumber = 0;
        var found = false;
        while (cardNumber < 5 && !found)
        {
            if (document.getElementById("playerCard" + cardNumber + "selected"))
            {found = true;}
            cardNumber++;
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            call.setAttribute("onclick", "compareHands()");
            call.childNodes[0].nodeValue = "Hold";
        }
    }
    if (id.indexOf("selected") >= 0){unselect(card);}
    else {select(card);}
    }
    ...
}
```

How `game()` is called:

```
window.onload = function openingScreen()
{
    var startGame = document.createElement("a");
    startGame.setAttribute("onclick", "game()");
    startGame.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Play"));
    window.table = document.getElementById("table");
    table.appendChild(startGame);
}
```

Comment: How is the game function called?

Comment: It is first called at the Opening screen:
    [code]window.onload = function openingScreen()
    {
 var startGame = document.createElement("a");
 startGame.setAttribute("onclick", "game()");
 startGame.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Play"));
 window.table = document.getElementById("table");
 table.appendChild(startGame);
    }[code]

Comment: Put this in the question not here in the comment... hard to read in the comment and is part of the question.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. Just a second.

Comment: There, I've edited it. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: it seems you are calling the game function but not storing or setting the result anywhere.  How are you calling `cardSelection`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is the result of confusion about Objects/*Classes*/Instances in javascript.

The critical point for you on this issue is the difference between `new game()` and `game()`;

```
var foo = new game()
```

- tells the JS engine to create a new object
- point that object's Prototype (not `prototype`) at `game`'s `prototype`
- and then invoke the function game, but for the sake of the body of that function `this` will refer to the created object.
- If the function doesn't return an object, assign our created object to `foo` (otherwise assign the function's return value to `foo`

Inside the body of your game function, you have `this.cardSelection = function (...`.
If you simply invoke `game` as a function, so just `game()`, without the `new` keyword, `this` inside the body of the function will be the window object! So you'll add `cardSelection` to the window object.

Also importantly: `game.cardSelection()` is looking for a function named `cardSelection` as a property on the **function** `game`.

Here's an example of using that style that would work:

```
var foo = function () {
    //do interesting stuff
}

foo.bar = function () {
    //do interesting stuff related to foo
}

foo.bar();
```

What you seem to be expecting would need to be written this way:

```
var game = function () {
    this.cardSelection = function () {
        //perform card selection!
    }
}

var aGame = new game();

aGame.cardSelection();
```

Or, if `cardSelection` does not need access to any private properties of the game, it could be written more efficiently as

```
var game = function () {
   //setup the game
};

game.prototype.cardSelection = function () {
   //perform card selection
};

var aGame = new game();

aGame.cardSelection();
```